# Laplace Equation in the upper half plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Assume $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^\infty_c\mathbb{(R)}$ function. I was asked to use the Fourier transform (in $x$) to obtain Poisson's integral formula solution to the Laplace equation in the upper half-plane
$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ for $-\infty< x < \infty, y > 0, u(x, 0) = f(x), |u| $ bounded.

---

Then the fourier transform of $u$ and $f$ are given by :

$\displaystyle \hat{u}(k,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,y)e^{-ikx}\text{d}x,$

$\displaystyle \hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}\text{d}x,$

and the boundary condition becomes $\hat{u}(k,0)=\hat{f}(k)$.

Since $\hat{u}_{yy}(k,y)=k^2 \hat{u}(k,y)$, we solve Laplace's equation for $y$ and obtain $\hat{u}(k,y)=A(k)e^{ky}+B(k)e^{-ky}.$

Then, taking in account the boundary condition we find $A(k)+B(k)=\hat{f}(k)$ and applying the reverse Fourier transformation we obtain $u(x,y)$.

---

I am not sure that whether this is correct or wrong somewhere as it feels that there is something missing as i did not even use the half plane property. Can anyone help me how to figure it out?

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to have boundedness, you want $\hat{u}(k,y)=A(k)e^{-|k|y}$.

Comment: yes and it is coming from my solution to $\hat{u}(k,y)$

Comment: ok now i have some solution to the above problem.
Since as we have $\hat{u}(k,y)=A(k)*e^{ky}+B(k)*e^{-ky}$and it is given that $|u|$ is bounded hence so does $|\hat{u}|$ and hence $\hat{u}(k,y)=A(k)*e^{-|k|y}$ and after applying the initial data i.e. $\hat{u}(k,0)=\hat{f}(k)$ we get $\hat{u}(k,y)=\hat{f}(k)*e^{-|k|y}$.
Now let $\hat{h}(k,y)=e^{-|k|y}$ then using the fourier inverse transformation we get $h(x,y)=\frac{2y}{\sqrt{2\pi}~*~(x^2+y^2)}$ and hence our ${u}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)h(x-t,y)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\frac{y}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dx$

Comment: I think that's correct.